# how to copy one byte array into another byte array?

Tags: java, udp, arrays, p2p, fileoutputstream

I'm working on a simple application to demonstrate P2P file transfers. The application takes a file, and sends over packet sized chunks of data. The receiver waits for these chunks to arrive. Its suppose to continuously add the incoming byte arrays to a larger byte array which will later become the completed file once all bytes have arrived. This is assuming there is no packet loss. For the sake of debugging I've been attempting to transfer a small txt file. I tried using a for loop and now System.arraycopy but the byte array for packetData does not appear to be copying over to the completeFile array correctly.

```
public void run() {
    try {
        byte[] completeFile = new byte[fileSize];//will become the complete file when all bytes have arrived

        receivingSocket = new DatagramSocket(49000);
        while (bytesReceived<fileSize) {
            System.out.println("@@@ Receiver waiting for packet");
            byte[] buf = new byte[1500]; // Actual Ethernet packet size is 1500 bytes
            // receive request
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
            receivingSocket.receive(packet);
            byte[] packetData = Arrays.copyOf(packet.getData(), packet.getLength());
            deliverData(packetData);
            if(headerReceived && packetsReceived>1)
            {
                //add incoming bytes to the completeFile
                System.arraycopy(packetData, 0, completeFile, bytesReceived, packetData.length);
                bytesReceived = bytesReceived + packetData.length;
            }
        }
        FileOutputStream fops = new FileOutputStream("D:\\Desktop\\testing2"+fileExtension);
        System.out.println("@@@ BUILDING FILE"); 
        fops.write(completeFile);
        fops.close(); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("@@@ SOMETHING WENT WRONG!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        stopListening();
    }
}
```

Comment: "does not appear to be copying over to the completeFile array correctly" what is it doing instead?

Comment: well when i used a for loop and used a print statment to print out the index, it would only print out the first index then crash. with system.arraycopy it just crashes at that line.

Comment: I'd generally recommend using NIO buffers for this, as they're designed specifically for this kind of data manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to copy anything. You can write to the file directly from the byte array used to construct the `DatagramPacket,` every time around the loop, and you can pass that byte array around to other methods directly, along with the length from the packet of course.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Im sorry

Comment: You don't need to  construct a huge array containing the entire file data and write it at the end. You can open the file before the loop, write the received data to the file every time time round the loop, and close the file after the loop. Basically `fops.write(packet.getData(), packet.getOffset(), packet.getLength());`